# UrlHelper.Action is not generating correct Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am generating URL inside my MVC4 Action Method.

```
redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext).Action(
                    "MyAction", "MyController", new { id = someVariable, id2= someVariable2});
```

Now the trouble is it's appending Id2 as Query parameter. I have a specific route defined in RouteConfig.cs that is like Controller/Action/Id/Id2

How can i force this to generate route specific URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a route set up in your RouteConfig.cs, you can call it by name using RouteUrl()

```
rectUrl = Url.RouteUrl("YourRouteName", new { id = someVariable, id2 = someVariable2 });
```

Comment: How can i specify controller and Action name in Url.RouteUrl?

Comment: rectUrl = Url.RouteUrl("YourRouteName", new { id = someVariable, id2 = someVariable2, controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" });

Comment: I am using RouteUrl in two places, once inside my Controller and Once in Ajax Jquery. What I am doing is I create a URL and Send it back through Ajax response and then redirect in my Client i-e window.location.href= response.redirectUrl. This works fine but when i try to use same Url.RouteUrl value inside my Controller with Rediect(url) it does not append http://localhost/ before my url. Why its works in JS and NOT in Action method inside my controller. If i use Request.Url.Scheme then it works. Is it the right way of doing this?

Comment: Hard to say if it's the "right" way without seeing more of your code, but RouteUrl() should give you a fully-qualified url, that you can redirect to like this    return new RedirectResult(url);